# Pandas Cumlative Max Reset on NA

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
2019-01-09 13:00:00-06:00  0.0  5264.927000
2019-01-09 13:05:00-06:00  1.0  5264.927028
2019-01-09 13:10:00-06:00  0.0  5244.075097
2019-01-09 13:15:00-06:00  0.0  5226.784019
2019-01-09 13:20:00-06:00  0.0  5235.085161
2019-01-09 13:25:00-06:00  0.0  5246.221935
2019-01-09 13:30:00-06:00  0.0  5232.491797
2019-01-09 13:35:00-06:00  0.0  5231.456668
2019-01-09 13:40:00-06:00  0.0  5234.495478
2019-01-09 13:45:00-06:00  0.0  5242.245801
2019-01-09 13:50:00-06:00  0.0  5241.228244
2019-01-09 13:55:00-06:00  0.0  5239.997655
2019-01-09 14:00:00-06:00  0.0  5243.712108
2019-01-09 14:05:00-06:00  0.0  5247.304100
2019-01-09 14:10:00-06:00  0.0  5250.996665
2019-01-09 14:15:00-06:00  0.0  5254.568331
2019-01-09 14:20:00-06:00  0.0  5254.568000
2019-01-09 14:25:00-06:00  1.0  5261.586980
2019-01-09 14:30:00-06:00  0.0  5262.187910
2019-01-09 14:35:00-06:00  0.0  5257.388773
2019-01-09 14:40:00-06:00  0.0  5255.861004
2019-01-09 14:45:00-06:00  0.0  5248.942361
2019-01-09 14:50:00-06:00  0.0  5246.232192
2019-01-09 14:55:00-06:00  0.0  5252.215607
2019-01-09 15:00:00-06:00  0.0  5252.628778
2019-01-09 15:05:00-06:00  0.0  5253.012436
2019-01-09 15:10:00-06:00  0.0  5248.225834
2019-01-09 15:15:00-06:00  0.0  5245.495417
2019-01-09 15:20:00-06:00  0.0  5240.674316
2019-01-09 15:25:00-06:00  0.0  5242.054722
```

The first columns can take `1` or `0` only. I would like to run a cumulative max on the second column but the cumulative max resets whenever we hit a 1 in the first column. The way I've been doing it is looping through and finding where the 1s are in column one and then do a cum-max on each section. I am hoping to find a faster way of doing this.

Comment: `df.groupby(df[1].cumsum())[2].cummax()`?

Comment: this works but if there are like millions of rows, i wonder how fast it can be.

Comment: For a 30M row DataFrame with 2M groups this takes ~ 3 seconds on my machine. That solution is concise, if you need something more performant then there are probably better ways, at the expense of brevity. And you and can squeeze a little more performance by adding `sort=False` to the `groupby`

Comment: `df.groupby(df[1].cumsum().values)[2].cummax()` will shave some time off too.

Comment: i wonder if the answer you guys provided is faster then the one below by @Narges Ayoubi

Comment: The simple solution is slower, especially if you use `.values` to access the underlying arrays to improve the performance of the accepted solution. I got it was about 30% faster for 100M rows, but again things like the number of groups will play a role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
col1 = df[1]
col2 = df[2]
group = (col1.sum() - col1.cumsum()) * (col2.max() + 1)
result = (col2 - group).cummax() + group
```

This method is much faster than groupby and for loop.

Comment: this doesn't work, the results are much larger then the original column 2

Comment: Aha, this method works for cumulative sum, rather than cumulative max. I misunderstood your question!